# Site not 100% although defined?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

A site I am working on does not fill the screen on iPad Pro and Small Laptop screens. I have set the site container to 100%, but there is still a gap to the right?

http://79.170.44.103/113events-temp.co.uk/

[image: Screen shot of gap to the right error]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem by your giving link. Additionally: please provide a full working example of your issue as code in your question.

Comment: What did you try so far? It is probably (certainly) a "margin" problem somewhere... we can't help with this piece of code, problem is coming from css... Btw "max-width" does NOT mean that it will use 100%, but may use 100%...

Comment: Use media queries or bootstrap to make it responsive..  or inspect and check is there any extra padding or margin..thanx

Comment: your slider's li is giving problem..

Comment: Your site is giving me a horizontal scrollbar in Mozilla, but not in Chromium. You may want to look into that. Oh, and the W3C validator says that there are characters with ASCII code 3 in your source.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem happens because of your slideshow. when i delete it, the web page work fine to fill the screen on iPad Pro and Small Laptop screens.

[image]